# Which area of research is the logical successor to Minsky's society of mind idea?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm curious if there is any body of research that could be considered as the logical successor to Marvin Minsky's "society of mind" idea? It seems as if the notion of agents plays a crucial role in his thinking. I'd be interested in reading more about recent efforts in this direction.

Comment: Could you be more specific. Multi-agent systems is a big area of research -- is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: It is close to what I was looking for. However, it seems like most multi-agent systems research that I've glanced at don't work on cognition per se, but more on the robotics side.